# How to pass Nested complex structure and Union from Managed C# dll to C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

Having exported methods from C++ dll and need to consume it from C#. The C++ method has complex nested structures and union as parameter. I could not send string data from C# to C++.

Below C++, pdll_sensor_test structure has name variable. Could not send value from C# to C++. It prints empty.

**Source.cpp  (C++)**

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
    enum pdll_test_id

    {
        dut_com_init = 0,
        cont_pkt_tx = 1,
    };

    struct pdll_sensor_test
    {
        pdll_test_id test_id;
        bool en;
        char name[13];
        int reg_addr;
    };

    union pdll_test_data
    {
        pdll_test_id id;
        pdll_sensor_test sensor;
    };

    struct pdll_device
    {
        bool is_active;
        pdll_test_data test;
    };

    __declspec(dllexport) int PdllDeviceMethod(pdll_device* pdlldevice)
    {
        printf("pdlldevice->is_active=%d\n", pdlldevice->is_active);
        printf("pdlldevice->test.sensor.test_id=%d\n", pdlldevice->test.sensor.test_id);
        printf("pdlldevice->test.sensor.en=%d\n", pdlldevice->test.sensor.en);
        printf("pdlldevice->test.sensor.name=%s\n", pdlldevice->test.sensor.name);
        printf("pdlldevice->test.sensor.reg_addr=%d\n", pdlldevice->test.sensor.reg_addr);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Program.cs  (C#)**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public enum pdll_test_id
        {
            dut_com_init = 0,
            cont_pkt_tx = 1,
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct pdll_sensor_test
        {
            public pdll_test_id test_id;
            public bool en;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 13)]
            public string name;
            public int reg_addr;
        };

        //This is union in C++
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct pdll_test_data
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public pdll_test_id id;
            [FieldOffset(4)]
            public pdll_sensor_test sensor;
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct pdll_device
        {
            public bool is_active;
            public pdll_test_data test;
        };

        [DllImport("CPPDynamicDLL.dll")]
        public static extern int PdllDeviceMethod(ref pdll_device pdlldevice);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is C# program");
            pdll_device pdllDevice = new pdll_device();
            pdllDevice.is_active = true;
            pdllDevice.test.id = pdll_test_id.dut_com_init;
            pdllDevice.test.sensor.test_id = pdll_test_id.cont_pkt_tx;
            pdllDevice.test.sensor.en = true;
            pdllDevice.test.sensor.name = "wsa";
            pdllDevice.test.sensor.reg_addr = 1024;
            var result = PdllDeviceMethod(ref pdllDevice);
        }
    }
}
```

I try use marshaling and was not able to send the variable name from c# to C++.

Comment: My go-to resource. Adam Nathan's com interop book, covers pinvoke too

Comment: Wrong [FieldOffset], should be 0.  But more to the point, there just isn't any need to use a union here.  The id fields always overlap.  So just declare a single struct with is_active, id, en, name and reg_addr fields.  Apply [In, Out] attributes to the parameter so the data is copied back after the call.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-classes-structures-and-unions#unions-sample, value types and reference types (such as the strings) are not permitted to overlap. The provided sample uses two variants of the C# structures to simulate the C++ union. I think that you can try a similar approach:

**C#**

```
public enum pdll_test_id : Int32
{
    dut_com_init = 0,
    cont_pkt_tx = 1,
};


[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi )]
public struct pdll_sensor_test
{
    public pdll_test_id test_id;
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.I1 )]
    public bool en;
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 13 )]
    public string name; 
    public int reg_addr;
};


[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct pdll_test_data_1
{
    public pdll_test_id id;
};


[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4 )]
public struct pdll_test_data_2
{
    public pdll_sensor_test sensor;
};


[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4 )]
public struct pdll_device_1
{
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.I1 )]
    public bool is_active;
    public pdll_test_data_1 test;
};



[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4 )]
public struct pdll_device_2
{
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.I1 )]
    public bool is_active;
    public pdll_test_data_2 test;
};


[DllImport( @"CPPDynamicDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
public static extern int PdllDeviceMethod( ref pdll_device_1 pdlldevice );

[DllImport( @"CPPDynamicDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
public static extern int PdllDeviceMethod( ref pdll_device_2 pdlldevice );


pdll_device_2 pdllDevice = new pdll_device_2( );
pdllDevice.is_active = true;
pdllDevice.test.sensor.test_id = pdll_test_id.cont_pkt_tx;
pdllDevice.test.sensor.en = true;
pdllDevice.test.sensor.name = "wsa";
pdllDevice.test.sensor.reg_addr = 1024;

var result = PdllDeviceMethod( ref pdllDevice );
```

The example also uses some additional declarations (maybe redundant) to make sure that C# communicates correctly with C++ in this experiment. You can also use the original unchanged C++ code and only adjust the C# declarations.

It is also possible to consider fixed arrays like fixed byte name[13] and pointers, however this requires activating the unsafe code option. Or maybe you can construct the data as a byte array and pass it to DLL.

Or it is possible to create an intermediate Class Library in C++/CLI that can interact with C# and C easier.

Therefore, if the DLL can be rebuilt, it is better to avoid unions.